# I can't access GitHub diff file with curl or by Java code

Tags: java, github, diff

I'm trying to access a diff file, but I'm getting a 404 response all the time.

```
import org.kohsuke.github.GHRepository;
import org.kohsuke.github.GitHub;

GHRepository gh = GitHub.connectUsingOAuth(accessToken).getRepository(shortRepoName);
URL url = gh.getPullRequest(1).getDiffUrl();
// I'm able to authorize and get the proper URL path

var con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
con.setRequestMethod("GET");
con.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/vnd.github.v3.diff");
con.getResponseMessage();
//Gives 404
```

When I use the URL from above in a browser, it changes (redirects) from:
https://github.com/Assamir/MyRepo/pull/1.diff
To
https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/Assamir/MyRepo/pull/1.diff?token=SOME_AUTH_TOKEN

I have tried current (classic) and new tokens in both cases, and I got the same result: 404.

My end goal is to have a diff beatwean two PR not commits.